# Switch list webpart view

Tags: jquery, list-view

I am looking for following solution with use of jQuery/SPdesigner:

Page with some buttons on the top as a control to switch list view located below.

Right now I have webparts showing different views and hiding them with jQuery, but it is not elegant at all... 
Is it possible to do it different way?

Comment: http://www.markrackley.net/2015/08/16/sharepoint-tabbed-web-partshillbillytabs-3-0/

Answer (score 0):

Just put the tabs in a Content Editor Web Part and make each tab link to the corresponding view.

I would reference a html file in the Content Edit Web Part on each page so that if it needs to be changed, you only have to change it in one location. If you need the active tab to be a different color, create an `active` class and set that in another content editor on each page, or use the URL string to detect which page you're on and set the active tab with javascript.